# If statement with multiple statements inside loops doesn't work

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have the follow procedure :

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE getCost(
     in  p_idp int(11), 
     out p_cost  double)
BEGIN
DECLARE strt double;
DECLARE stop double;
DECLARE diff double;
DECLARE p_hs INTEGER;
DECLARE p_hf INTEGER;
DECLARE p_hcost double;
DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE i INTEGER;
    -- declare cursor
DECLARE tariffe_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT hs,hf,cost FROM tariffe ORDER BY hs;

    -- declare NOT FOUND handler
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;

SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(data_inizio) INTO strt
FROM prenotazioni WHERE IdP = p_idp;

SET stop = UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
SET diff = stop - strt;

SET diff = diff / 3600;

SET i = 0;
SET p_cost = 0;

WHILE i < diff
DO

    OPEN tariffe_cursor;

    get_tariffe: LOOP

        FETCH next FROM tariffe_cursor INTO p_hs,p_hf,p_hcost;

        IF v_finished = 1 THEN 
            LEAVE get_tariffe;
        END IF;

        IF (i >= p_hs AND i < p_hf) THEN
            SET p_cost = p_cost + p_hcost;
            SET v_finished = 1;
        END IF; 

    END LOOP get_tariffe;

    CLOSE tariffe_cursor;

    SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;

IF diff < 0.25 THEN
    SET p_cost = 0;
END IF; 

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Table tariffe has 2 records:

1. hs = 0, hf = 3, hcost = 3
2. hs = 3, hf = 1000, hcost = 2

Suppose DIFF = 1.50 -> Expect p_cost to be 6

Suppose DIFF = 3.75 -> Expect p_cost to be 11

but p_cost is always 3

Tried to use some INSERTs (into a temp table) to check the WHILE loop and the cursor loop and realized that the

```
IF (i >= p_hs AND i < p_hf) THEN
```

is computed true only when i = 0 (first while loop) but when i > 0 is always computed as false.

F.ex. when i = 1 the first cursor FETCH returns hs=0,hf=3,hcost=3, but IF seems to be false

What I'm doing wrong?

I've also tried (with no success)

```
IF (i >= p_hs) AND (i < p_hf)
IF i >= p_hs AND i < p_hf
```

LOGIC:

Diff is the number of hours between start and stop (renting period).

Tariffe Table contains rental cost: from 0 to 3 hours -> 3 euros, from 3 upto 1000 -> 2 euros.

While loop iterates for every single hour of rental

Cursor loop check for the right hourly cost and add it to p_cost

Comment: @Uueerdo The query has `ORDER BY hs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you never set `v_finished` back to `0` when you leave the `get_tariffe` loop and continue the `while i < diff` loop. So on subsequent iterations, `if v_finished = 1` is always true and you leave the loop before adding to `p_cost`.

Put

```
SET v_vinished = 0;
```

after

```
OPEN tariffe_cursor;
```

But I don't think you'll ever get `11` as a result. You do `SET v_finished = 1;` after adding the first `p_hcost`, so it will never process the second row of the table. I'm not sure what your intended logic is to get `11`. Maybe you should just take out the line that sets `v_finished`.

Comment: Thanks Barmar...I forget to set the v_finished back to 0: that was the problem.

Comment: I updated my question to explain the logic, so the question will be clearer

Comment: Probably easier to do what you want using arithmetic rather than nested loops.